# Match only for 2 level deep pages

Tags: javascript, regex

So need to match for only pages ending with .html down two levels deep.

match

```
http://www.example.com/bedroom/beds/select-queen-platform-bed.html
```

not match

```
http://www.example.com/bedroom/select-queen-platform-bed.html
http://www.example.com/bedroom/
http://www.example.com/
http://www.example.com/bedroom/beds/level3/select-queen-platform-bed.html
```

so basically it should match domain-name.com/level-1/level-2/page-name.html

The expression I have now doesn't match for some of these possibilities. What should I use?

current regex

```
/*/.*html$
```

Comment: Try [`/^https?:\/\/(?:[^\/]+\/){3}[^\/.]+\.html$/.test(url)`](https://regex101.com/r/Bhk3bS/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
^http:\/\/(?:(?:[^\/]+)\/){3}[^\/]+\.html$
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/2enekg/3)